# NaN - cuando quiero mostrar lo que retorna el metodo me sale NaN

Tags: java, poo

/*Método calcularIMC(): calculara si la persona está en su peso ideal (peso en
kg/(altura^2 en mt2)). Si esta fórmula da por resultado un valor menor que 20, la
función devuelve un -1. Si la fórmula da por resultado un número entre 20 y 25
(incluidos), significa que el peso está por debajo de su peso ideal y la función
devuelve un 0. Finalmente, si el resultado de la fórmula es un valor mayor que 25
significa que la persona tiene sobrepeso, y la función devuelve un 1. Se recomienda
hacer uso de constantes para devolver estos valores.

```
 */
public int calcularIMC(Persona p) {
    
    int pesoIdeal=0, bajoPeso=-1, sobrePeso = 1;

    double imc = p.getPeso() / (Math.pow(p.getAltura(), 2));

    System.out.println("imc : " + imc);

    if (imc< 20) {
        return bajoPeso;
    } else if (imc >= 20 && imc <= 25) {
        return pesoIdeal;
    } else {
        return sobrePeso;
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenida. El enunciado es lo de menos. Lo importante y que está faltando es, qué devuelve `getPeso` y `getAltura`? NaN se obtiene al dividir 0 por 0 y al calcular la raíz cuadrada de un número negativo. Así que si ambos son 0, el problema está en otra parte.

Comment: Hola Macarena, tu método ***jamas*** puede devolver un "NaN", sin importar nada de lo que hagas dentro de el, esto se debe a que trabajas con un "else" que ante cualquier tipo de dato "erróneo" que tenga **imc** devuelve "1", osea, el problema no está aquí, sino en como manejas lo que este método te devuelve, deberías editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que corresponda.

Comment: Sugerencia: declara las constantes cómo `readonly` o `const`.